# Passing arguments or param to fixture function

Tags: python, pytest

I'm exploring the fixtures in py.test and I have similar question to the one asked more than a year ago: [Can params passed to pytest fixture be passed in as a variable?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13925366/can-params-passed-to-pytest-fixture-be-passed-in-as-a-variable)
I'm wondering if it's now possible in newer versions of py.test to somehow choose a subset of params asking for a fixture function.

Let say I have a simple function and a test:

```
def func(a, b):
    return (a - b)**3 + 10

@pytest.fixture(scope="module", params=[(7,11), (7,0), (3,0)])
def fix_func(request): 
    output = func(*request.param)
    return output

def test_1(fix_func):
    assert fix_func <= 500
```

And now I woull like to add a second test only for param = (7,11):

```
def test_2(fix_func):
    assert fix_func > 0
```

If choosing a subset of params is still not possible, another way of solving this issue might be to move params from fixture to tests, something like that:

```
@pytest.fixture(scope="module")
def fix_func(request, param): 
    output = func(*param)
    return output

@pytest.mark.parametrize("arg", [(7,11), (7,0), (3,0)])
def test_1(fix_func(arg)):
    assert fix_func <= 500

@pytest.mark.parametrize("arg", [(7,11)])
def test_2(fix_func(arg)):
    assert fix_func > 0
```

But this example also doesn't work.
If there is any other short/"elegant" way to use different sets of fixtures for different tests (writing only one fixture function)?

Answer (score 1):

You cannot nest function calls within the defined parameters for another function's signature. You need to move the inner function into the outer function and call it there:

```
@pytest.mark.parametrize("arg", [(7,11), (7,0), (3,0)])
def test_1(arg):
    assert fix_func(arg) <= 500
```

Comment: I'm afraid this version also doesn't work with fixtures. It only works if the fix_func is a normal function.
I'm guessing it might be impossible to use fixture function in this situation...

Comment: This suggestion is correct IMHO, you should really call the function under test in the test function instead of in a fixture.