# How to use pytest to ensure an object was created properly?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pytest

I have a file that is saved in a particular format, and a class that will create an object based on the data in the file.

I want to ensure that all values in the file/string were extracted correctly by testing each attribute in the object.

Here is a simplified version of what I'm doing:

*classlist.py*

```
import re

class ClassList:
    def __init__(self, data):
        values = re.findall('name=(.*?)\$age=(.*?)\$', data)

        self.students = [Student(name, int(age)) for name, age in values]

class Student:
    def __init__(self, name, age):
        self.name = name
        self.age = age
```

*test_classlist.py*

```
import pytest
from classlist import ClassList

def single_data():
    text = 'name=alex$age=20$'
    return ClassList(text)

def double_data():
    text = 'name=taylor$age=23$' \
           'name=morgan$age=25$' 
    return ClassList(text)


@pytest.mark.parametrize('classinfo, expected', [
        (single_data(), ['alex']),
        (double_data(), ['taylor', 'morgan'])
])
def test_name(classinfo, expected):
    result = [student.name for student in classinfo.students]

    assert result == expected

@pytest.mark.parametrize('classinfo, expected', [
        (single_data(), [20]),
        (double_data(), [23, 25])
])
def test_age(classinfo, expected):
    result = [student.age for student in classinfo.students]

    assert result == expected
```

I want to create objects based on different data and use them as a parametrized value.

My current setup *works*, although there is the unnecessary overheard of creating the object for each test. I'd want them to be created once.

If I try doing the following:

```
...
@pytest.fixture(scope='module') # fixture added
def double_data():
    text = 'name=taylor$age=23$' \
           'name=morgan$age=25$' 
    return ClassList(text)


@pytest.mark.parametrize('classinfo, expected', [
        (single_data, ['alex']),
        (double_data, ['taylor', 'morgan']) # () removed
])
def test_name(classinfo, expected):
    result = [student.name for student in classinfo.students]

    assert result == expected
...
```

`AttributeError: 'function' object has no attribute 'students'`

...it doesn't work as it references the function rather than the fixture.

Furthermore, the code in `test_name` and `test_age` is almost identical. In my actual code, I'm doing this for about 12 attributes. Should/can this be merged into a single function? How?

How can I clean up my test code?

Thanks!

Edit:

I feel this is relevant, but I'm unsure how make it work for my situation: [Can params passed to pytest fixture be passed in as a variable?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13925366/can-params-passed-to-pytest-fixture-be-passed-in-as-a-variable)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> > My current setup works, although there is the unnecessary overheard of creating the object for each test. I'd want them to be created once.

This smells like unnecessary pre-optimization to me, but if you care about this, then run the functions that create your data to test at module level, so they only run once.

For example:

```
...
def single_data():
    text = 'name=alex$age=20$'
    return ClassList(text)

def double_data():
    text = 'name=taylor$age=23$' \
           'name=morgan$age=25$' 
    return ClassList(text)


double_data_object = double_data()

single_data_object = single_data()


@pytest.mark.parametrize('classinfo, expected', [
        (single_data_object, ['alex']),
        (double_data_object, ['taylor', 'morgan'])
])
def test_name(classinfo, expected):
    result = [student.name for student in classinfo.students]

    assert result == expected

@pytest.mark.parametrize('classinfo, expected', [
        (single_data_object, [20]),
        (double_data_object, [23, 25])
])
def test_age(classinfo, expected):
...
```

> Furthermore, the code in test_name and test_age is almost identical.
>   In my actual code, I'm doing this for about 12 attributes. Should/can
>   this be merged into a single function? How?
>
> How can I clean up my test code?

A couple of ways to do this, but from your example, provide an [equality magic method](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#object.__eq__) to the `Student` class and use that to test your code (also add a [**repr**](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#object.__repr__) for sane representation of your object):

```
class Student:
    def __init__(self, name, age):
        self.name = name
        self.age = age

    def __eq__(self, other):
        return (self.name, self.age) == (other.name, other.age)

    def __repr__(self):
        return 'Student(name={}, age={})'.format(self.name, self.age)
```

Then your test can look like this:

```
@pytest.mark.parametrize('classinfo, expected', [
        (single_data(), [Student('alex', 20)]),
        (double_data(), [Student('taylor', 23), Student('morgan', 25)]),
])
def test_student(classinfo, expected):
    assert classinfo.students == expected
```

Comment: I've tried using the equality magic method, but in my actual code, there are about 12 attributes (some of which are quite lengthy), so I find that it becomes difficult to compare them both and determine exactly where the issue is. Should I just improve the formatting? Or is there a better way?

Comment: @jake is the problem creating the equality method or the unit test? sounds like you are using the class to store data, look into a [namedtuple](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.namedtuple) or the [attrs](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/attrs/17.2.0) module, as it provides these methods for free and it fits these use case better.

Answer (score 2):

You can add one `fixture` which returns object of that class and call that fixture before every test. I have done some changes and create a fixture `get_object` in `test_classlist.py` while `classlist.py` is as it is.

`get_object` will give you an object of that class and you can use that object in test function via `request` module. I have assigned that class object in `request.instance.cobj`. The same you can access in test function.

What I am getting from your description is you want to create object of `ClassList`. If i am not getting wrong ,the below solution should work for you. Try this.

```
import pytest
from classlist import ClassList

def single_data():
    text = 'name=alex$age=20$'
    print text
    return ClassList(text)

def double_data():
    text = 'name=taylor$age=23$' \
           'name=morgan$age=25$'
    return ClassList(text)

@pytest.fixture
def get_object(request):
    classobj= request.getfuncargvalue('classinfo')()
    request.instance.cobj = classobj


class Test_clist:

    @pytest.mark.parametrize('classinfo, expected', [
            (single_data, ['alex']),
            (double_data, ['taylor', 'morgan']) # () removed
    ])
    @pytest.mark.usefixtures('get_object')
    def test_name(self,classinfo,expected,request):
        result = [student.name for student in request.instance.cobj.students]
        print result
        print expected
        assert result == expected
```

Comment: Nice. This is sort of what I was after.

Two followup questions:
1. It's not necessary to add a scope to the fixture?
2. Why do the tests have to be inside a class for this to work?

Comment: 1.If you dont' define scope of fixture, default scope would be `function`.. 2.By putting method into class, scope of the test would also be `function`. To use `request` scope of both test and fixture must be same.